# Rotational Ehrenfest theorem derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I'm trying to derive the rotational analog to the Ehrenfest theorem, but I dont know why I don't get the expression, we want to derive,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle L \rangle= \langle N \rangle \quad ; \quad N=r\times (-\nabla V)$$
For this I used the known Ehrenfest theorems,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x \rangle=\frac{1}{m} \langle p \rangle \quad ; \quad \frac{d}{dt}\langle p \rangle= \langle -\nabla V \rangle$$

So using the definitions and the Levi Civita notation, we want to proof that

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle L_i \rangle= \frac{d}{dt}\langle \epsilon_{ijk}x_j p_k \rangle= \langle N_i \rangle=\langle \epsilon_{ijk}x_j (-\nabla V)_k \rangle
\end{align}

Operating to the left side of the equation,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle L_i \rangle= \frac{d}{dt}\langle \epsilon_{ijk}x_j p_k \rangle= \epsilon_{ijk}\langle\dot{x}_j p_k+\dot{p}_kx_j  \rangle= \epsilon_{ijk}\langle\frac{ p_jp_k}{m}+x_j(-\nabla V)_k  \rangle$$

So as we can see from the right and left parts are the same but a $\frac{ p_jp_k}{m}$ term, that make not the equalty true, it's obvious that I'm doing something wrong or missing something but I have not idea of what it is.

Comment: I don't know if the fact of having expected values play an important role in the derivation, but I supose the error is due to some expected value properties

Comment: Note that $\epsilon_{ijk} p_j p_k$ is the $i$th component of $\vec{p} \times \vec{p}$